# Save of model return error

Tags: java, javascript, spring, rest, backbone.js

I'm trying to save model with this code:

```
this.model.save({},
{
   success: function (model, response) {
      alert("ok");
   },
   error: function (model, response) {
      alert("error");
   }
});
```

I catch the error callback. But my REST API returns a 200 status:

```
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/json
Status code:200
```

On the server side I have following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}/image/{type}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes  = "application/json", produces =  "application/json")
   public void uploadImage(..) {
       response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
       response.setContentType("application/json");
   }
```

Why backbone.js call error callback instead success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the annotated source for Backbone http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html, save appears to expect an object in response from the server. If you change your uploadImage method so that it does not return void, (returning an empty object {} would likely work), the success handler should be triggered.